# Device debug works but not release

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to troubleshoot why a release build doesn't work on the device but a debug version does.  With a release build, the app starts, default PNG displays and the app dies.  I've commented everything out of applicationDidFinishLaunching, which means it isn't a code issue.  I see this error in the console:

Mon Jan 18 21:17:39 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[1579] : error: MachTask::StartExceptionThread (): task invalid, exception thread start failed.

I have it configured as a device release build and have assigned my app store provisioning profile to it.  Any ideas on what could be wrong or what the above error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the app store provisioning profile to load onto your device. That will only work for submitting it to Apple. You can make an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile to use, but your Development profile should be enough.

Comment: Yes - the developer profile works.  I made a duplicate of the release configuration and signed it with the developer profile.  If I don't crash in this configuration, chances are my submission to Apple should not crash either?

Comment: Yep, that's right. It's a little strange that your app store build allowed you to get as far as a Default.png. Usually the build fails before it can even run. You might want to try "Clean Build", then quit Xcode, delete the Build folder in your project and re-build. The build process is still buggy in Xcode.

Comment: Cool. Thanks.  I had recently got a rejection because of a [NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:].  I use two custom static libraries and I'm betting one of them wasn't an update to date build.  Since I don't see the issue anymore with my Release build, I'm hoping all is well now.

Comment: I hope so. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Get Info on your project or target and compare your properties between Debug and Release configurations.  Instinct says, something must be different that doesn't need to be different.

Comment: Is there a way to compare those without flipping through them and eye balling everything?

Comment: Show Package Contents of your .xcodeproj package, and open project.pbxproj in a text editor.  Search for "Release" and "Debug" and you'll find short sections with all the overridden properties for those configurations.  I'd start a new project and compare against that project's .pbxproj as well, just to see what differences are normal.

Comment: Kevin, there's UI for that right in the Build Settings inspector. Show "Settings Defined at This Level" instead of "All Settings."